# How do I access the object inside a script file within my own jsx file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using React, and I am wondering how I can access the object that I have included as `script` in my `html` file within my own `jsx` file

This  is an example that I got:

```
<script src="url-to-some-script"></script>

<div id="an-id-wrapper">
  <div id="an-id"></div>
</div>

<script>
   var settings = { config: "some-config", id: "an-id" };
   TheObjectThatINeedToAccessFromScript.initialize(settings);
</script>
```

I want to do something like:

1. Add the script in my html file
2. Place the div in some React component
3. Be able to reach the `TheObjectThatINeedToAccessFromScript` so I can call `initialize` on it within my `jsx` file. Eg trough an `import TheObjectThatINeedToAccessFromScript from "some-where";`

How can I do an `import` on this script?

Answer (score 0):

It is now available on the window object, so I can access it trough there:
`window.TheObjectThatINeedToAccessFromScript.initialize(settings);`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to `export` your `initialize()` function from the script, and import it within your component. E.g:

```js
function initialize() {
  /*[...]*/
}

export { initialize };
```

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { initialize } from './yourScriptFile';

/*[...]*/

function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    initialize();
  }, []);

  return <div>{/*[...]*/}</div>
}
```

Unless it's absolutely vital, as a best practice, try to avoid binding things to the window. It can end in tears.

Comment: I am sorry that I did now made my self understood. I meant that I wantet to use the initialize method frome someone elses script file (a third party). So I wantet to know how I could import that script file, which I added to my html-file, into my own React jsx-file.

I figured it out that I could access it via the window object directly in my jsx-file (check out my own answer to this question below). Thank you so much for taking your time!

Comment: Oh I see, yeh if it's from a third party, unless they provide a package of some kind, the window's all you've got! No problem, good luck!